# How to force Mac (Yosemite) to use USB Bluetooth instead of internal?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, continuity

I'm on an older Mac Pro, and I bought the ASUS USB-BT400 so that I can use Yosemite's Handoff feature. The problem is, I don't know how to disable the internal Bluetooth and force my machine to use the USB Bluetooth instead. I searched around but didn't find anything that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Continuity Activation Tool](https://github.com/dokterdok/Continuity-Activation-Tool/) is a great app for doing all of the command-line stuff necessary to enable Continuity, and it claims to be able to work with USB dongles.

Comment: I know all about it. :) But it requires Bluetooth 4.0, which is why I bought this USB dongle which I can't get working.

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack Are you on version 2.0.0? That's what I'm on, and after I press 1 for "Activate Continuity," it says it'll go with the dongle if it detects you plugging one in.

Comment: Yeah, I run `contitool.sh -d` and it says `Verifying Bluetooth version...          NOT OK. Your hardware doesn't support Bluetooth 4.0, necessary for Continuity. Current LMP Version=4, expected 6.`

Comment: How old is your Mac Pro? [This graphic](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dokterdok/Continuity-Activation-Tool/beta/CompatibilityChart-13.12.2014.png) from the developers shows what CAT can and can't do.

Comment: Early 2009. USB 4.0 dongle is plugged in.

Comment: When I ran "Activate Continuity," it said "If you want to activate Continuity using a USB dongle, then plug-it in now." Try unplugging it and then only plugging it in when prompted?

Comment: Ok, will try. Let me ask: can I revert to all the standard kext drivers if something goes haywire?

Comment: I have to reactivate Continuity every time I reinstall the OS or get a software update, so I assume an OS X reinstall would do the trick.

Comment: Weird, it says the script will continue once it detects a USB BT 4.0 dongle, I plug it in, and nothing happens.

Comment: That's strange. I'd recommend taking it up with [the developer](https://github.com/dokterdok).

Comment: I probably have a dud dongle. :( I plug it in and I don't see it show up in the Apple system info.

Comment: Oh, if the computer itself isn't detecting the dongle, that's probably it.

Comment: Never mind, it's there. BCM20702A0. I'll hit up the developer and check back in later, thanks!

Comment: Got it! This was documented in the issues page for CAT. I had to disable Bluetooth, plug in the dongle, enable Bluetooth, and then the tool worked. Handoff is working like a charm!

Answer (score 10):

To force your system to use an external Bluetooth controller instead of the internal one, open Terminal and type:

```
sudo nvram bluetoothHostControllerSwitchBehavior=always
```

then reboot. To revert to the default OS X behavior, type:

```
sudo nvram -d bluetoothHostControllerSwitchBehavior
```

You may need to turn off (or un-pair) Bluetooth accessories that are currently using your internal Bluetooth controller, as they can prevent the dongle from being detected by the Continuity Activation Tool.

Comment: this worked for me

Comment: (Hackintosh) sudo nvram bluetoothHostControllerSwitchBehavior=never