# Wireless headphone experiences audio interruptions when many devices are connected to Bluetooth. Can I use two HCI controllers on my iMac?

Tags: macos, usb, bluetooth, efi, driver

**Computer**: iMac (27-inch Late 2013).
**OS**: macOS: 10.15.7

I need to connect 3 devices (magic keyboard, mouse and trackpad) to the internal Bluetooth module and 1 device ([wireless headphones](https://www.fixed.zone/en/product/fixed-boom-bluetooth-stereo-true-wireless-earphones-id68)) to an external [USB Bluetooth adapter](https://ikupiec.pl/Product/Index?Id=9371). I'm experiencing problems with an audio interruption on headphones when all 4 devices (magic keyboard, mouse, trackpad and wireless headphones) are connected to the internal Bluetooth module at the same time. The audio works fine when the only devices connected are keyboard and headphones.

`Bluetooth Explorer` allows me to select and make either of them active but I don't know how to make **both** active simultaneously.

[image]

This thread - [Possible to use two HCI controllers concurrently?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/390427/possible-to-use-two-hci-controllers-concurrently/410773) - suggests it is possible.

If my approach is not practical or possible, other ideas / solution are welcome too. Thanks.

Comment: WHere are you stuck? The Linked question would appear to cover the method.

Comment: @Tetsujin I understand, but what's the setup/process behind that? How/where do I set it up?

Comment: @sfxedit Hi. Thanks for your comment. I have edited my whole question. See above.

Comment: Ok, great. According to [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201171):
*The official Bluetooth specifications say seven is the maximum number of Bluetooth devices that can be connected to your Mac at once. However, **three to four devices is a practical limit**, depending on the types of devices used. Some devices require more Bluetooth data, so they're more demanding than other devices. Data-intensive devices might reduce the total number of devices that can be active at the same time.* So you are on the right path that it would be better to use another external Bluetooth adapter.

Comment: Well, I guess my only option here is to contact Apple directly. I'll do that this week and post an update when I have any.

Comment: I've contacted Apple today and they said it's not possible to use two HCI controllers at the same time. They didn't suggest any workaround/solution for my problem either. Final conclusion, this specific problem can't be solved. Pretty disappointing, but now I know.

Comment: Just for tracking purposes, here's my thread on ASC: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252341263